# HTML5 input color with editable input

Tags: javascript, html, input, colors

I need a color picker, the HTML5's one is fine (the pop-up of `<input type="color"/>` ), but the input is not editable. I want to be able to write there the hex code of color manually too.

Is it possible to use html5 color picker with an editable input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you cannot indeed not use it the way you would like.

The only way to create that which you want is to create one yourself using html in combination javascript/css, which is what I would recommend for now anyhow - since the HTML5 color picker is not readily implemented in all browsers (I believe only chrome and opera? support it right now).

If you do not want to go through the trouble of implementing it yourself, there are lots of pre-made color pickers available online.

For example, try http://jscolor.com/

Although not originally implementing your feature, it is easily extendable if you know a bit of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such a thing using just HTML5.